# Clicking a button once joypad

Tags: lua

I'm creating a program that is going to play a video game. When it reads that their is an enemy in RAM value 0x0016 it needs to press B. I think maybe because of my while loop B is getting spammed way too much? I'm not sure. At the moment, on FCEUX it says the B button is getting pressed, but it stays orange. I need the B button to only be pressed once.

Here's my code:

```
JoypadB = {B=true}
JoypadRight = {right=true}

while (true) do
   c = memory.readbyte(0x0016);

   if (c == 6 ) then
      joypad.set(1,JoypadB)

   else
      joypad.set(1,JoypadRight)

   end;

   gui.text(100,100,c);
   emu.print(c);

    emu.frameadvance();
end;
```

Comment: We need more information on what your desired outcome is and what the program is currently doing to assist. The code looks syntactically fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question isn't really about FCEUX, and it isn't really about lua. It's 95% just about programming but a bit of videogaming commonsense will help. The button gets pressed repeatedly because 0x0016 contains 6 repeatedly. Add a toggle to effect repeated shots as long as there's an enemy. You may need to pick a different turbo interval than every-other, which is what's done in this example:

```
JoypadB = {B=true}
JoypadRight = {right=true}
toggle = 0
while (true) do
    c = memory.readbyte(0x0016);
    if (c == 6) then
        if(toggle==0) then
            joypad.set(1,JoypadB)
            toggle = 1;
        else
            joypad.set(1,JoypadRight)
            toggle = 0;
        end
    else
        joypad.set(1,JoypadRight)
    end;
    emu.frameadvance();
end;
```

Or, to do what you literally asked for, assuming the enemy only takes one shot to kill, then just press the button once and wait until the next time the enemy disappears and  then reappears:

```
c = memory.readbyte(0x0016);
joypad.set(1,JoypadRight)
if (c == 6) then
    if(toggle==0) then
        joypad.set(1,JoypadB)
        toggle = 1;
    end
else
    toggle = 0;
end;
```